# Disable the attachment control in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I want to diable the attachment control in editform.aspx using jaavscript or anyother options in sharepoint 2013.

Comment: Can you edit the aspx page at all?

Comment: I dont know to edit. I did disable the lite item column using SP service library in Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you can, you can just go into the .aspx page and delete the formfield and formlabel corresponding to the attachment field.

If you want to use javascript, all you need to do is write

```
document.getElementById("ID_of_attachment_field").style.display = 'none';
```

Comment: Just know that this just makes it hidden.  I don't know what kind of security you want on your site, but someone can still set an image to be uploaded using their own Jscript.

Comment: Thank you!, I dont have persmission to edit the form in SPD.

Comment: Ahh, I see.  Okay then, you can just set it like that.  Like I said, all it does is just hide the web part.  If someone wants to be pesky, they can still upload their own file, but they can't do it at a glance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5933157/how-to-remove-an-html-element-using-javascript  Here's a link to write javascript code to completely remove HTML elements from your aspx once the page renders.

Comment: Ok, I will try this options.

Comment: How to upload their own image, or how to hide the web part?

Comment: I am trying this option in Sharepoint list item editform.. Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want anyone to attach files to your list items, the best way to accomplish this is:
List Settings -> Advanced Settings -> Attachments : Disabled

This will also remove the attachment control from the default forms.

If you are just looking to turn off the attachment control rendering on the web page then Brandon's answer will work just fine :)

Comment: I want to disable the attachment in Listitem Editform.aspx page.

Comment: Yes - this will do that if you did not create a custom form using InfoPath. If you do have a custom InfoPath form with the attachment field it would no longer work either.